# Cheap wheeled robot without tether (does not need to be programable)

Tags: control, wheeled-robot

I am looking for **cheap** wheeled robot that can be controlled remotely. I do not really care about how (RF, Bluetooth, WiFi, IR, other?), as long as I can control around 10 robots without interference in a small arena (they are always in the line of sight).

I would like to emphasize that I do not need them to be programmable and it is important that they are cheap.

Comment: Can you give more detail?It sounds like all you need are 10 remote control toy cars.They are cheap and can be purchased anywhere.What do you need that makes it a robot?

Comment: 10 remote control cars with independent channels will be fine. Can you point me to some? Most of the cheap ones the channel is not selectable in so many ways.